# How to add title on the background img in html

Tags: html, css

[image]

in the picture is my code and what shall I add to make "Lanlan's Dinner" show on the background1.jpg?  This code is what the textbook saying about how to add a background img under your title. But in this code, only the picture shows, the title does not show.
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Keep reading the book... also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Clue: "alt attribute specifies an **alt**ernate text for an image"

Comment: We do not like photos of code, we like the code in the question.

Comment: One of the main issues is it looks like you've placed the image withing the `head` of your document.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like this. Place the heading inside a div and set the background of the div to an image as suggested. Then set the position of the heading to relative and have the ability to adjust the text placement on the image.

I think this is what you wanted? No js is really needed for this.

```css
.header {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x50) no-repeat;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  
}
.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    Hello, world
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, the image only show a little portion.

Comment: I would try adjusting the width and height of the header class using the 'width' and 'height' attributes to better match your image size.

Answer (score 0):

To have an image as a background, use the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) CSS property (or the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) property). Note the associated `background-*` properties, many of them are useful to arrange the image (e.g, I'm using `background-repeat` below so it won't tile the element).

```css
h1 {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x50) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello, world
</h1>
```

Comment: like that, background image should not be completly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What if we use the follow code?

```html
<figure>
  <img
  src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50"
  alt="An awesome picture"> 
  <figcaption>Text below the image.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

`<figcaption>` is [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) for these types of situations, so you should make a use of it.

Edit; since the question was, how to add background image above title, here's how you do it:

```html
<figure>
      <figcaption>Text above the image.</figcaption>
      <img
      src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50"
      alt="An awesome picture"> 
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you put in the `alt` attribute is an *alternative* text. It is shown if the image is not loaded (not yet or not at all). It is also used by search engines to "understand" what is in the image.

If you want to display text on your page, you have to put that text inside your `h1` markup:

```
<h1><img src="image.jpg">your title</h1>
```

and then apply some styles to display that as you want:

```css
h1{
  position:relative;
}

h1 .title{
  position: absolute;

/*set that values to position your title, you can also use right and bottom, regarding on how you want to place your title */
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1> 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50"/>
  <span class="title">your title</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: This will make "your title" display _next to_ the image.

Answer (score -1):

If you want show title on the picture in html, you must do something:`<img src="images/background1.jpg" alt="Lanlan's Dinner" title="Lanlan's Dinner" width="700" height="700" />`.
The ALT attribute is used to display the value when the image is not displayed.

Best,
thanhnt

Comment: your title will not be displayed like that.